# Will there be any force of attraction or repulsion between an electrified body and a non-electrified body?

Tags: electricity, electrostatics, charge, dipole

Up to my knowledge an electrified (charged) body can attract a non-electrified (neutral) body. I thought this because, when we bring a charged (suppose negatively charged) body near a neutral one. Electrified body can attract a non-electrified body by the opposite charge induced on neutral body due to electrostatic induction, then the answer to the above question would be likely to say that electrified body exerts attractive force on non-electrified body.
But going through the Wikipedia's encyclopedia of [electric charge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge), I found the following line:

> *No force, either of attraction or of repulsion, can be observed between an electrified body and a body not electrified.[3]*

My view on the concept is contradictory to the statement.

**EDIT:** I have seen a article supporting my view.You can see at the bottom of [this](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/estatics/u8l1c.cfm) link page about interaction between charged(electrified) and neutral(non-electrified)body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you continued to read on, it goes on to say:

> Actually, all bodies are electrified, but may appear not to be so by the
>   relative similar charge of neighboring objects in the environment. An
>   object further electrified + or – creates an equivalent or opposite
>   charge by default in neighboring objects, until those charges can
>   equalize.

Therefore, since all bodies are electrified or can be electrified, your statement is correct.

Answer (score 5):

It is true that there is no (electrostatic) force between an electrified body and a body not electrified. (Let's ignore gravitational force for now.)
It is also true that all bodies (in earth or earth-like environment) are electrified or will be electrified if approached by another electrified body.
But in general, not all bodies can be electrified. For instance, neutrons, which make up neutron stars, cannot be attracted (electrostatically) by another body.

Comment: I agree that all bodies can't be electrified by electrostatic induction.Because the body to be electrified must be conductor,so that charge distribution takes place easily in the conductor when a charged body is brought near it.Like as I have already said that a electrified body can exert attractive force on the non-electrified body due to charge induced on non-electrified body by electrostatic induction.But you came up with different answer saying that there would be no force between an electrified body and a body not electrified.But I am not quite well convinced with it.

Comment: @CURIE. My points are two-fold. One, It does not have to be a conductor. A conductor can easily be electrified, but dielectrics can be electrified too. A better term to describe would be 'polarized', so long as some surface charge is induced. Two, neutrons cannot be (electrically) polarized, so they are not attracted by the usual matter on earth.

Comment: .For clarity I repeat once again that there will be no force between an electrified body and a body not electrified in certain cases like the one you said about neutrons.But we can't say it applies to all.Because we have examples where an electrified body attracts a non-electrified body by inducing charge like the one I said about bringing a conductor(non-electrified) near charged body.However if thought neutrons can also attract each other by induction but here we have up and down quark.The up quark in one neutron can attract down quark of another neutron creating attractive force.